# negative variance example

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I came across the following matrix.
[image: CovMatrix]

I notice, that it is symmetric and real and has an eigenvalue of -0.01091786.

This must mean, that there exists a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{10}$ for which it holds
$$ xVx^T<0$$
but I have no idea how to come about an example of such vector? - I especially want to know, if there is an example of a vector $x$ that has that property and also has the property $\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i =1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is positive, it cannot have a negative e.v. My guess is numerical error.

Comment: @user619894, it is not positive, it has negative entries, my mistake.

Comment: @Viktor What did you use to compute the eigenvalue? Presumably, whatever programming language or software you used has a function for computing the associated eigenvector

Comment: Matlab: `[V,D] = eig(M)`. Python: `vals, vecs = numpy.linalg.eig(M)`.

Comment: Do you have more accuracy to the matrix, are they really 1 significant digit?

Comment: @BenGrossmann i am using Maple, but I generally do not expect the eigenvector entries to sum to 1. But I can of cause just scale. Thanks!

user619894, this is the precise entries.

Comment: @Viktor Technically there is a chance that you run into trouble if the entries of the eiegnvectors sum to zero (which means that scaling wouldn't work). But yes, that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks ! I managed to find one, i will post it later

Answer (score 1):

Here is one trick for finding eigenvectors associated with an eigenvalue. It is guaranteed to work if the characteristic polynomial is also the minimal polynomial, but may fail otherwise:

If $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p(A) = 0$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $p(t) = (t - \lambda)q(t)$ where the polynomial $q(t)$ can be found by synthetic division.

Now $p(A) = (A - \lambda)q(A) = 0$. If $q(A)$ has any non-zero columns, those columns have to be eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$.